# Generate SerialVersionUID for scala classes in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a bunch of scala case classes that extend `Serializable` and I would like Intellij to generate the `@SerialVersionUID` annotation for me.

Are there any settings I can change or any plugin available for this ?
I already tried the `GenerateSerialVersionUID` plugin but it only works for Java classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ Idea generating serialVersionUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912287/intellij-idea-generating-serialversionuid) - see https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/185-generateserialversionuid

Comment: @prayagupd This is not a duplicate. I am talking about scala not Java. Please read the whole question

Comment: Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8894.