# Should serialVersionUID be unique for different classes?

Tags: java, serialization

```
class A implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5L;
    ...
}
```

and

```
class B implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6L;
    ...
}
```

then it is necessary to give unique `serialVersionUID` to both classes.

So can I assign `serialVersionUID = 5L` for both classes?

I read following links

[Why generate long serialVersionUID instead of a simple 1L?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/888335/3131537)

[What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/285793/3131537)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can. Serial versions of different classes are independent and do not interfere each other.

PS 
Eclipse even proposes you to set `serialVersionID` by default value that is `1L`.

Answer (score 11):

`serialVersionUID` is needed to remember versions of the class. It should be same while serializing and deserializing. It is a good programming practice to provide this value rather than JVM assigning one(generally it is hash). It is not necessary for two classes to have unique values.

Comment: i want to know "It should be unique for single class but may possible it is same for two different class"

Comment: @Aniket could you please explain this line. "It is not necessary for two classes to have unique values"

Comment: It means two different classes can have same **serialVersionUID** value.

Answer (score 4):

`serialVersionUID` can be anything.

But the best practice is to **start with the lowest number (for example `0L`) and update it whenever you make a change in class which affects serialization**, for example, *adding/updating/removing* a field, in which case you should increase the version number from `0L` to `1L` and so on.

Comment: @Reman Sahasi, "adding/updating/removing a field, in which case you should increase the version number from 0L to 1L and so on." - Here if we  updated 0L to 1L then how  we should get previously serialized objects? Since previously serialized objects are stored with 0L.

Comment: @Raj why do _you_ want to get previously serialized objects? This property is basically used during serialization process to verify that a loaded class and the serialized object are compatible.

Comment: @Reman Sahasi, Lets assume, If you saved one object in a file using serialization with 0L serialVersionUId then later you added few columns  into class (That is class modified/fields removed) and you updated serialVersionUID from 0L to 1L then you saved latest data with 1L into the file. So in this file if you have both versions Serialized objects, then how can we get previously stored data with 0L with same Serialization class?

Answer (score 1):

SerialVersionUUID is an identifier used by a compiler to serialize/deserialize an object. This id is a private member to the class.

Creating new uuid for every serializable is good to have control over the serialization/deserialization process but it need NOT be unique among different classes.