# What should I set serialVersionUID to be?

Tags: java, serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does it matter what I choose for serialVersionUID when extending Serializable classes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605828/does-it-matter-what-i-choose-for-serialversionuid-when-extending-serializable-cla)
>   [Why generate long serialVersionUID instead of a simple 1L?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888335/why-generate-long-serialversionuid-instead-of-a-simple-1l)

Are there any best practices or common naming schemes associated with setting the `serialVersionUID`?

I feel that most people start from `0` and increment from there. I personally started using the date (e.g. `09052011`) because I felt that it was more descriptive.

Comment: Have you googled "java serialversionuid best practice"?  Anything look authoritative?  Josh Bloch says it is fine to pick a number out of thin air, so if a date works for you it's probably fine.

Comment: This might help you: [Does it matter what I choose for serialVersionUID when extending Serializable classes in  java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605828/does-it-matter-what-i-choose-for-serialversionuid-when-extending-serializable-cla/605832#605832)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to prefer one manual value for a serialVersionUID over another. But you should never increment at all, you should adjust your readObject()/writeObject()/writeReplace()/readResolve()/serializableFields to preserve binary compatibility, not have a scheme in mind for when you break it.

Answer (score 0):

You should usually have the serialVersionUID as a private static final field in your class; you can choose any value. If you don't specify one, a value is generated automatically (this approach can lead to problems as it is compiler (object structure) dependent. There is also a tool (serialVer) that ships with jdk that can be used to generate the id. The specs should be able to help on details.

Comment: @EJP : please explain why "you can choose any value" doesn't qualify as an answer; when I have already stated the code convention to be followed while choosing the value.

Comment: OK but that's the only part that is an answer: the rest is really irrelevant.

Comment: well that's your personal opinion which you are entitled to; I do not consider giving the context to an answer as irrelevant (also the question did really ask of best practices).